# we are re-indexing our product flat data and our category flat data in magento and it we are getting an integrity constraint error

Tags: magento, zend-framework, e-commerce

When doing it by SSH, we got an error:

Product Flat Data index process unknown error:

```
exception ‘PDOException’ with message ‘SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint vio lation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (` db96761_final`.<result 2 when explaining filename ‘#sql-4d76_775b93’>, CONSTRAIN T `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REF ERENCES `catalog_product_entity)’ in /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.c om/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 
Stack trace: 
#0 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.  php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#1 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pd o/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#2 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php( 300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#3 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstra ct.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#4 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Ab stract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(’ALTER TABLE `ca...’, Array) 
#5 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/ Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(’ALTER TABLE `ca...’, Array) 
#6 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/ Mysql.php(340): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(’ALTER TABLE `ca...’) 
#7 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/ Mysql.php(2569): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query(’ALTER TABLE `ca...’) 
#8 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addF oreignKey(’FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...’, ‘catalog_product...’, ‘entity_id’, ‘catalog_prod uct...’, ‘entity_id’, ‘CASCADE’, ‘CASCADE’) 
#9 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Prod uct_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1) 
#10 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_ Indexer->reindexAll() 
#11 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer-> reindexAll() 
#12 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll() 
#13 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll() 
#14 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/shell/indexer.php(158): M age_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything() 
#15 /nfs/c06/h05/mnt/96761/domains/jumastudio.com/html/shell/indexer.php(198): M age_Shell_Compiler->run() 
#16 {main}
```

Comment: If you do it from the back end it works? How do you try to do it from SSH? Programmatically? It sounds like a permission error to me.

Comment: Try truncating the product flat tables manually and then running the index process again.

Comment: @vbak It wasn't working from backend as well. But the problem with backend is it doesn't give you much flexibility to work with. By ssh into the server, you get to manipulate the content and the db using a cli which then gives you a lot of options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out. Apparently magento stores catalog_product_flat tables and the content in those tables is not updated. So the solution is as follows:

1) Backup the database

2) Switch off the Use Flat Product and Category options in Magento and switch the Index mode from the Product Flat Data to Manual update.

3) Truncate the catalog_product_flat tables

4) Reindex via ssh: php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat